# R plot dynamic wind direction as arrow over time

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly, segment

I want to plot the **wind** over a very long time,thus a dynamic plot is a nice choice for others to choose the time range. And I want to display the wind direction as **arrows**; wind speed could be **line**.

But it will be messy if I add arrows to every line above, and it seems hard to add more date to x axis. What the final result I want to get is like this:

[image]

Is it possible to plot the wind-arrow plot in R?

Plus: here is the demo data for plot

```
structure(list(date = c("2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", 
"2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", 
"2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", 
"2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", 
"2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", 
"2016-04-01", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", 
"2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", 
"2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", 
"2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", 
"2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-02"
), time = c("0:00:00", "1:00:00", "2:00:00", "3:00:00", "4:00:00", 
"5:00:00", "6:00:00", "7:00:00", "8:00:00", "9:00:00", "10:00:00", 
"11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", 
"17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", "20:00:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", 
"23:00:00", "0:00:00", "1:00:00", "2:00:00", "3:00:00", "4:00:00", 
"5:00:00", "6:00:00", "7:00:00", "8:00:00", "9:00:00", "10:00:00", 
"11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", 
"17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", "20:00:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", 
"23:00:00"), ws = c(0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.6, 0.9, 0.4, 0.9, 2.3, 2, 2.5, 2.6, 2.4, 2, 2.2, 1.7, 1.2, 
1, 1, 1.4, 1.1, 1.4, 0.8, 1, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.3, 2, 2.1, 
2.7, 2.2, 2.1, 2.5, 1.9, 2, 1.7, 1.9, 1.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4), wd = c(179, 
151.5, 200, 178.7, 205.5, 115.1, 110.9, 175.7, 192.9, 121, 117.5, 
171.7, 204.8, 160.7, 169.3, 171, 169.4, 172.8, 154.5, 170.6, 
151, 131.1, 105.3, 109.5, 141.9, 137.1, 113.7, 116.6, 88.7, 110.1, 
99.9, 105.5, 98.4, 101.3, 128.6, 146.9, 148.1, 148.4, 152.5, 
144.1, 145, 160, 179.2, 147.3, 156.6, 147.1, 158, 157.9)), .Names = c("date", 
"time", "ws", "wd"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

________________________________update________________________________________

Sorry for not emphasising my problem.

Thanks @koekenbakker ,the function doing well in plotting the wind direction and the speed in one plot.Otherwise,my problem may focus more on how to convert the wind plot to a **dynamic** plot.(dynamic in date selection is enough)

Comment: You should be able to do this with `geom_line` and `geom_spoke` with `arrow = arrow()` (you'll need to convert `wd` to radians), but for the life of me I can't get the arrows to point in the right directions.

Comment: Having the date & time as in a datetime (eg POSIXct) class would make plotting the x-axis much easier

Comment: @alistaire well I have try to do this use `geom_line` and `geom_segment`with`arrow=arrow()` using the `sin()` and `cos()` .But it still be hard to dynamic display the result.

Comment: @Richard Telford Sorry for that demo data,I have handle the two columns using `paste()` and `strptime()`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Arrowhead` function in the `shape` package with the `angle` argument:

> angle of arrowhead (anti-clockwise, relative to x-axis), in degrees
>   [0,360]; either one value or a vector

I'm not sure this matches with your description of wind direction, perhaps you need to subtract your wind directions from 360 degrees or something similar.

```
library(shape)
plot(1:nrow(a), rep(1,nrow(a)), pch=NA, ylim=c(0,5))
Arrowhead(x0 = 1:nrow(a), y0 = a$ws, angle=a$wd)
```

Comment: Yeah,this answer satisfy one part of my problem,about the direction of the wind,and the speed of wind is also display very well.But there is another problem I want solve is how to dynamic select the date range. In **ggplot2**,I can creat simlar plot like the **Arrowhead** do.For a ggplot object ,I could do the dynamic use the **ggplotly**function,but it seems less **stable**,I have look for the package **dygraph**,but in its example demo ,I find it do well in line chart,maybe not an arrow or a segment chart?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that part of the question.